# Why should we use RequestQueue in android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am an android beginner learner .I want to know why should we use RequestQueue in our codes and pass JsonObjectRequest to RequestQueue as an argument .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG63b.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Volley uses two classes, RequestQueue and Request

*RequestQueue is where all the requests are queued up that has to be executed, 
it also manages the worker threads 
and maintain network call in the background
also it handles reading from and writing to the cache
and also parsing the response and delivering the parsed response to mainthread.*

*Request is where network request is constructed.The request object has 3 major request:*

1. JSON requests

JsonObjectRequest — A request for retrieving a JSONObject response body at a given URL
.
                  JsonArrayRequest — For  retrieving JSON Array from the server.

Request takes 3 parameters that are passed to the constructor.

1. Request Method Type(GET,POST,PUT...).
2. Resource URL of the required object.
3. ResponseListener whose callback method contains the response.
4. ErrorListener whose callback method has an error has been occurred with request (provided error code and optional user-readable).

The snippet for the implementation of both JsonObjectRequest and JsonArrayRequest  is as below:

```
 String mJSONURLString= "json_url";
   JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, mJSONURLString, null,
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

               }
           },
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

               }
           });
   //add JsonObjectRequest request to queue
   requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

   JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
           new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

               }
           },
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

               }
           });
   //add JsonArrayRequest to queue
   requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

2. StringRequest — To retrieve response body as String from the server.

   - Method Type(GET,POST,...).
   - The Resource URL.
   - The Event Listeners.

Code snippet as below:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Do something with the response
    }
},
```

3. ImageRequest-To receive an image from the server,the network call has the similar structure as other network requests.

Code snippet as below:

```
   String mImageURLString= "";
   ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(mImageURLString= , new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
           // Assign the response to an ImageView
           ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
       }
   }, 0,0, null);//Image width,Image height
   //add request to queue
   requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Volley, RequestQueue will queue your requests on worker thread and then delivers the response to main thread. The reason why you need it is that you are not allowed to perform network operations on the main thread if your application targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Thus you will not get [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException).